# How to parse a nested JSON array having a combination of strings and integers to a POJO in Java?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, pojo, objectmapper

The Java application I am working on calls an external API that gives the following response in JSON format.

```
 {
    "response": {
        "version": "1.2.0",
        "data": [
            [
                "*",
                [
                    "core1",
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "core2",
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "core3",
                    1
                ]

            ],
            [
                "*",
                [
                    "{\"frame\":[\"frame1\",\"frame2\"]}",
                    10
                ]
            ],
            [
                "*",
                [
                    null,
                    10
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to map the response to a POJO using the following;

```
private String version; 
private  List<List<Object>> values;
```

Although the values of ***data*** are mapped as , I am unable to iterate and extract each content from it.
My requirement is to get *core1*, *core2*, *core3* to a variable *coreLists* and frame to *frameList* from the values of *data*. Is there a better way to map ***data*** field to POJO correctly and iterate and extract the values and assign each to separate lists?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't want to parse it directly to `List<List<Object>>` because in the end, I have to use parser to parse `"{\"frame\":[\"frame1\",\"frame2\"]}"` from string `Json/HashMap` anyway.

**Step 1: parse json string to your POJO**

I use Gson as a parser

```
        String json = "{\"response\":{\"version\":\"1.2.0\",\"data\":[[\"*\",[\"core1\",1],[\"core2\",1],[\"core3\",1]],[\"*\",[\"{\\\"frame\\\":[\\\"frame1\\\",\\\"frame2\\\"]}\",10]],[\"*\",[null,10]]]}}";
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<>(){}.getType());
        Map<String, Object> response = map.get("response");
        String version = (String) response.get("version");

        List<List<Object>> values = (List<List<Object>>) response.get("data");

        MyPOJO pojo = new MyPOJO(version, values);
```

Okay, let's inspect `pojo` (god bless VSCode):

[image]

As you can see, elements in arrays of values arrays could be either String `*` or array-ception so we have to check the type of it.

**Step 2: extract coreLists**

Because you don't mention how `core` will appear so I'll assume that it only appears in the first element of the values array. You can add more checks for safer. ie: string or double

```
        List<String> coreLists = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object coreCandidate : pojo.getValues().get(0)) {
            if (coreCandidate instanceof ArrayList) {
                List<Object> temp = (List<Object>)coreCandidate;
                coreLists.add((String) temp.get(0));
            }
        }
```

**Step 3: extract frameList**

Do the same as extract `coreLists` but add Gson parser one more time

```
        List<String> frameList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object coreCandidate : pojo.getValues().get(1)) {
            if (coreCandidate instanceof ArrayList) {
                List<Object> temp = (List<Object>) coreCandidate;
                Map<String, List<String>> frames = new Gson().fromJson((String) temp.get(0), new TypeToken<>() {}.getType());
                frameList.addAll(frames.get("frame"));
            }
        }
```

If this is good enough, feels free to vote up